# Is it okay to update the Pull Request with commits before code is reviewed and commented on?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, git-commit, pull-request

I have created a pull request of my branch after work is done, and have assigned it to code reviewers. After that I opened the pull request and observed my changes. Before anyone could review, I found 1 or 2 simple mistakes. I have corrected them on my local. If I commit and push them, the pull request will get updated.

Is it professionally correct to update pull request before it is reviewed and commented on by the code reviewers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it really depends on who you are working with but I don't think it should be a problem. If you have to change the code then what else can you do. Better to fix it then let your reviewers look at broken code. You should try to catch "simple mistakes" before you send it out though as it can look kind of sloppy if it happens all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with you updating your pull request if you think it requires that.  I do this all the time, and in general I think both you and your reviewers will benefit from this.  You benefit because it means both parties will spend less time later on dealing with these mistakes.  And were you to *not* fix the mistakes now, you will just have to do it later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's OK to do that.

It's even a good practice that the guys of github encourage to do by creating the pull request the sooner (even before the development is finished) and that way, the discussion could start early and development choices could be made in common....